# Build Failed in Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, liferay, liferay-6

I am getting Build Failed, while deploying the Portlets,Themes and Layouts in liferay 6.2 on ubuntu OS .
The console messages are:

The Build Failed Message on Console:

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/scrum-6.2/plugins/layouttpl/20x80-layouttpl/build.xml:7: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/scrum-6.2/plugins/layouttpl/build-common-layouttpl.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/scrum-6.2/plugins/build-common-plugin.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/scrum-6.2/plugins/build-common.xml:47: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/scrum-6.2/plugins/build-common-ivy.xml:17: The specified destination is a directory
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Is this full console log?

Comment: Which version of Ant are you using?  It looks like it's failing when it tries to download the Ivy JAR, then freaks out because the specified destination is an existing folder.  Current versions of Ant should be smart enough to know that it should just be downloading the file into the folder.

Comment: that is the full console log

Comment: i am using the  ant Apache Ant version 1.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the build failed issue

The following file is missing in plugins:

---> build.username.properties file

And inside the .ivy folder,cache folder and ivy-2.3.0.jar files are missed.

I just have added the above things in plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Solution -> Edit build-common-ivy.xml and change line 17 so that it looks like this:

```
   dest="${ivy.home}/ivy-${ivy.version}.jar"
```

Also, it complains that you need Ant 1.8, so be sure to upgrade to 1.8.